# Multiple Instance Issue with ColdFusion 10: "Bad Gateway Error"

Tags: coldfusion, instance, gateway

I am creating a multiple instance setup on my developer edition of ColdFusion. I am running on Maverics. My guide to the process is [this article by Rob Brooks-Bilson](http://rob.brooks-bilson.com/index.cfm/2012/2/23/Configuring-Multiple-Instances-of-ColdFusion-10-with-Apache-Virtual-Hosts).

I did everything right. However I get the 'Bad Gateway Error' when I try to ping the ColdFusion Administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have any of the following issues:

1. The `workermap.properties` file for your particular instance (cf10/config/wsconfig/1/) has the instance name spelled wrong.
2. Recheck the `worker.properties` file that you have added the content properly. This step is very much prone to copy-paste error. There are two places you need to add your instance name: In the list and then the port configuration (copying from the existing).
3. There is some glitch in your `mod_jk` file.
4. last but not the least please re-check that your `server.xml` (cf10//runtime/conf/) has been edited properly. Also please check if the value of the port attribute of the SERVER tag and the CONNECTOR tag are different. It happens that due to some glitch they might get generated as the same.

Comment: @user3620294: So which of the possible issues was the cause of your problem?

Comment: @3524344: My bad I missed to mention that. My problem was the server.xml file. The port id was same. I incremented the 'Server' tag's by 1 and then the issue was solved..